# Initial value problem $y'=e^{-y^{2}}-1.$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let y be a solution of $y'=e^{-y^{2}}-1$ on $[0,1]$ which satisfy $y(0)=0$. Then how to prove that $y=0$ on $[0,1]$? According to me as the function $e^{-y^{2}}-1$ is Lipsctiz and continuos on $[0,1]$ so the given ODE has unique solution in a sufficient right neighbourhood of zero. But I am confused how it is zero in while inverval ? Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x)= e^{-x^2} -1$. It is not hard to verify that $f$ is globally Lipschitz, hence the solution to the differential equation is unique and defined
for the entire interval (in fact, the entire real line).

Let $y_1(x) = 0$, then $y_1(0) = 0$ and $y_1$ satisfies the differential equation, hence it is the unique solution passing through $(0,0)$.

Comment: Sir if $f$ is Lipschitz globally them it has unique solution globally??

Comment: It has a unique solution passing through the specified initial condition for all $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: But the Picard theorem gives uniqueness in a particular neighbourhood of the point. Actually I have very little knowledge of Ode.

Comment: Please can you give me some simple references for this concept from where I can clear about uniqueness of solutions of Ode??

Comment: There are various ways of approaching this. The simplest in this case is to note that the system is time invariant. Suppose $y$ is the unique solution on $(-\epsilon, \epsilon)$. Since $y=0$ satisfies the equation, we see that $y(x) = 0$ for $x \in (-\epsilon, \epsilon)$. Continuity shows that $y(\epsilon) = 0$. Now consider the system with initial condition $0$ at $x=\epsilon$. Since the system is time invariant, we see that the solution is defined on $(-\epsilon, 2 \epsilon)$. Then we repeat as much as necessary.

Comment: Yes yes I got the point ...thanks a lot....you give clear cut analysis....

Comment: Kolmogorov & Fomin, "Introductory Real Analysis". Jerrold E. Marsden, "Elementary classical analysis". Kantorovich & Akilov, "Functional analysis"

Comment: But again I got a confusion that what if initial condition are not zero at zero. Like $y(a)=b$. Please.

Comment: How does that relate to the question?

Comment: Uniqueness of solution globally if f is globally Lipsticz and initial conditions are like y(a)=b unlike we use zero and continuity of y.

Comment: Since $f$ is globally Lipschitz you can use the contraction mapping principle to show that the there is a unique solution on any bounded interval.

Comment: If y(0)=0 and f is globally Lipschitz then I got your point that how solution is globally zero. But I am asking what if initial conditions are like y(a) =b where b is non zero...

Comment: I don't understand, what are you asking? If the initial condition is non zero, then the solution will not be zero, ever.

Comment: I am asking that how to prove that solution is unique if f is globally Lipschitz and initial condition like y(0)=1. It is clear that solution is non zero in this case. But how to prove uniqueness in this case like you prove very clearly that zero is unique solution if y(0)=0.

Comment: The above example was a special case, since $0$ is an equilibrium point. In general, uniqueness follows from the right hand side being locally Lipschitz.

Comment: I have a theorem which says that if $f$ is Lipschitz on $\{ (x,y): a\leq x\leq b,-\infty<y<\infty \}$ then the ODE $y'=f(x,y)$ has unique solution on $[a,b]$ .But how to extent the same result on $\mathbb{R}$ in place of $[a,b]$?

Comment: If $f$ is Lipschitz everywhere, then for **any** $a,b$ there is a unique solution on $[a,b]$. So, let $y_n$ be the solution on  the interval $[-n,n]$. Then, by uniqueness, we must have $y_n = y_{n+1}$ on $[-n,n]$, so this lets us define a solution $y$ everywhere.

Comment: Yes sir i got it...thanks for yours nice discussion...you help me really a lot...thanks...

Comment: Glad to be able to help!

Comment: Can i say that the same result is not true iF $f$ is Lipschitz in any bounded neighbourhood of $(a,b)$ as i have counterexample $y'=1+y^{2},y(0)=1$ in this case solution $y=tan(x+\pi/4)$ is not defined in whole $\mathbb{R}$? Can i say that if $f$ is Lipschitz in any bounded neighbourhood of $(a,b)$ then if solution is defined over any interval containing $a$ then solution is unique in that interval. In particular if solution is defined on $\mathbb{R}$ then it is unique in $\mathbb{R}?$

Comment: If there is a solution defined on the real line and $f$ is locally Lipschitz, then the solution is unique.

Comment: ok thanks  a lot....